# Submitting a jQuery ajax form with two submit buttons

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, input, submit

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="/vote/" method="post" class="vote_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="10" />
    <input type="image" src="vote_down.png" class="vote_down" name="submit" value="down" />
    <input type="image" src="vote_up.png" class="vote_up" name="submit" value="up" />
</form>
```

When I bind to the form's submit (`$("vote_form").submit()`), I don't seem to have access to which image the user clicked on. So I'm trying to bind to clicking on the image itself (`$(".vote_down, .vote_up").click()`), which always submits the form, regardless of whether I try

- return false;
- event.stopPropogation(); or
- event.preventDefault();

because all of those are form events.

1. Should I attach my $.post() to the form.submit() event, and if so, how do I tell which input the user clicked on, or
2. Should I attach my $.post() to the image click, and if so, how do  I prevent the form from submitting also.

Here is what my jQuery code looks like now:

```
$(".vote_up, .vote_down").click(function (event) {
    $form = $(this).parent("form");
    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.find("input").serialize() + {
        'submit': $(this).attr("value")
    }, function (data) {
        // do something with data
    });
    return false; // <--- This doesn't prevent form from submitting; what does!?
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Based on Emmett's answer, my ideal fix for this was just to kill the form's submit with Javascript itself, like this:

```
$(".vote_form").submit(function() { return false; });
```

And that totally worked.

For completeness, some of my JS code in the original post need a little love. For example, the way I was adding to the serialize function didn't seem to work. This did:

```
    $form.serialize() + "&submit="+ $(this).attr("value")
```

Here's my entire jQuery code:

```
$(".vote_form").submit(function() { return false; });
$(".vote_up, .vote_down").click(function(event) {
    $form = $(this).parent("form");
    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize() + "&submit="+ $(this).attr("value"), function(data) {
        // do something with response (data)
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this. Shortened my existing attempt quite a bit!

Comment: Why not avoid hardcoding `"&submit="` by using `$this.attr("name")`?

Comment: @bngtlrs I'd guess because that's a function call overhead that's simply unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulSkinner Yes, the function call is unnecessary here, but I would reject calling it overhead, since it will typically not be called very frequently. My bet would be that the reusability will be worth omitting possibly premature optimization.

Comment: I'm using `.ajaxForm()`, my solution for auto send is `.ajaxForm({}).submit();`. Will send ajax call without submit button and on custom event.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use a hidden field, and have the onclick event update its value.
This gives you access from javascript, as well as on the server where the hidden field
will get posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the form submit on the click of the images. This will work with the preventDefault().

```
var vote;
$(".vote_up, .vote_down").click(function(event) {
    vote = $(this).attr("class");
    $(".vote_form").trigger("submit");
});

$(".vote_form").submit(function(event) { 
    $form = $(this);
    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize() + "&submit="+ vote, function(data) {
        // do something with response (data)
    });     
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get how `return false` and `preventDefault` failed to do their job. Maybe try replacing the image buttons with linked images:

```
<a href="#" class="vote_down"><img src="vote_down.png"/></a>

$('#vote_form > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //one way to know which image was clicked
    alert($(this).attr('class'));

    $.post(...
});
```

You can always ensure that a form does not submit by binding to the submit event, e.g.:

```
$('#vote_form').submit(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Like I said in the question, I have done what you've suggested in the second part, but I do not have access to which input the user clicked on.  Further, I do not want to switch to linked images -- while that may work with Ajax, I still want my form to work for users w/o Javascript, as it currently does (and wouldn't with plain images).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding onsubmit="return false;" to your form, and then submitting your form with javascript:

```
<form action="/vote/" method="post" name="vote_form" class="vote_form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="10" />
    <input type="image" src="vote_down.png" class="vote_down" name="submit" value="down" onclick="imageClicked(this)"/>
    <input type="image" src="vote_up.png" class="vote_up" name="submit" value="up" onclick="imageClicked(this)"/>
</form>

<script>
function imageClicked(img) {
    alert(img.className);
    document.forms["vote_form"].submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: While I'm not convinced this is an elegant solution, it really led me to a workable fix, which is to add:

$(".vote_form").submit(function() { return false; });

(I certainly don't want to add "onsubmit='return false;'" to the form since I want the form to work w/o Ajax.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out the jquery From Plugin which as all sorts of nice tools for submitting forms via ajax.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0):

Without resorting to the Form plugin (which you should use) you should be handling the submit event instead. The code would stay pretty close to the original:

```
$("form").submit(function()) {
  $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    // work with the response
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Like I said in the original question, I can do this, but I still need to know what image-input the user clicked on within this function. event.target == the form, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = jQuery('#myform');

var data = form.serialize();

// add the button to the form data
var btn = jQuery('button[name=mybuttonname]').attr('value');
data += '&yourpostname=' + btn;

var ajax = jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    statusCode: {
        404: function () {
            alert("page not found");
        }
    }
});
... rest of your code ...
```