# form doesn't pass buttons value via jquery, why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, button

I have written something like that in PHP:

```
 echo '<form method="post" id="delete">';
    while ($users = $getChildUsers -> fetch_array()){
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$users['user_id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$users['user_mail'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$users['user_phone'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>';
                    echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="del_child_user();" name="user_id" value="'.$users['id'].'">Usuń </button>';
            echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</form>';
```

and used function:

```
function del_child_user(){
$(document).on('submit', '#delete', function()
{
    $.post('scripts/child_user.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data)
    {
        $("#del_msg").html(data);
    });
    return false;
});}
```

When I try to return the value of `$_POST['user_id']`, there is no value to display. When I write `print_r($_POST)`, it gives me back an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As I know `serialize` processes only `<input>` elements

Comment: Where are your inputs in the form?

Comment: i was trying o use input type="submit" instead of button but it gave me the same effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery / ajax form not passing button data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732861/jquery-ajax-form-not-passing-button-data)

Comment: not exactly, because question which u posted is about using AJAX in which I'm even worse than Jquery :D

Comment: From https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ : only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. **No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button.**

Comment: buttons and submit inputs aren't considered to be "successful controls" and there is no any input elements in your form thats why its showing empty array, add any input textbox or any other input elements in your form and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, that your definition is wrong on the button

You defined:

`echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="del_child_user();" name="user_id" value="'.**$users['id']**.'">Usuń </button>';`

But on the top, you wrote $users_['user_id']

Maybe its only a typo?

## Addition:

Look here, i created an example for you to reach your goal without using forms.

https://jsfiddle.net/9zbt9h2k/6/

Comment: nope, $users['user_id'] is different than $users['id'] in my db, in button used $users['id'] cuz it is INT value and it is not displayed at page

Comment: and in the file Child_user.php i'm calling $_POST['user_id'] which is the name of mentioned button.

Comment: Then its the answer from  MysterX... serialize only indexes formfields, but not the buttons.

Look here:
https://jsfiddle.net/9zbt9h2k/

Remove the input=hidden, and the response is empty.

Comment: So you are telling me that i have to create for every single one user collected via Query from DB, new form with button and hidden input ? And for each have separate function? ;/

Comment: No, not realy....

You dont have to define so many forms, btw, you can do it without it (forms). Give me some minutes, ill produce an example for you in a new answer.

Comment: Have a look here ... i did make an example how to reach your goal without forms. https://jsfiddle.net/9zbt9h2k/6/

I did update the main answer with an addition with the same content as in this comment.

Comment: Thank You a lot :) it finally works the way i wanted to :D