# Submit with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I specify which submit button to submit with?

The current example just submits the first submit button, with $("form").submit(); but how can I make it so it chooses the submit button by id or name?

```
<html>
<script>
$("form").submit();
</script>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" />

//other inputs


<input type="submit" value="Enter" name="enter" id="enter">
<input type="submit" value="Void" name="void" id="void">
<input type="submit" value="Refund" name="refund" id="refund">

</form>

</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicated IDs btw.

Comment: You also should only have one id per element

Comment: @FabrícioMatté oops that was just a copy and paste typo, sorry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365059/submitting-a-jquery-ajax-form-with-two-submit-buttons

Comment: No prob, back to the topic, a submit event triggered from JS does not send any submit button value from what I remember. I guess Blender's solution is your best shot, though I haven't tested it.

Comment: Some html errors may cause unexpected results (1) self-closed the form opening tag (2) input tags should be self closed

Comment: @NabilKadimi: Input tags are self-closing. You only need to explicitly specify that in XHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## By id

You can select the element by id easily with `$('#my_btn')` and you can click on it using the jQuery method `click()`.

## By name (or any other attribute

Other attributes are a bit harded (but not complex)
You select the element with `$('input[name=some_name]')`

## Examlpe using your code

Here is an example which shows how you can get elements by name and click on them, click the submit buttons to see what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/99v93/2/

Answer (score 2):

Simulate a click to that element:

```
$("#circle2").click();
```

Also, you don't need `action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"`. Forms submit to the current page by default.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why do you want to submit the same form with 3 different buttons? 
It is a bad structure. Your code also has all the 3 buttons with the "id" attribute which is included in the `<input>` tag twice.

Based on your question, I could figure out you would want the submit button to say different things under different conditions.

Have a single button like this :

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
```

You could always change what your button says, or how it looks like with JQuery :

```
if(condition){
$('#submit').val('.....');
// You can also change more stuff as you want.
}
```

Then you would want to submit the form

```
$('#submit').click(function(e)){
e.preventDefault();
$('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: When you click a submit button, the POST request sent by the browser contains the `name` and `value` attributes of the button. Here, even if you had JavaScript turned off, you could enter, void and refund from the same form.

Comment: Thank you, my answer applies when Javascript is on, since the user already has Javascript in his code.

Comment: Yes, but that's the whole problem. By submitting the form like this, you don't send that extra parameter.

Comment: How about having a hidden input field that is set by PHP?