# on submit of dynamically generated form, find which submit button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have multiple forms which are dynamically generated at runtime by a template engine, in order to generate an ajax request on their submission I have used the `on` method to delegate the event.

```
$("#friendRequestsList").on("submit", "[id^=friendReqResponse-form]", function(){
    var form = this;
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        url:'URL',
        type:'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            DO SOMETHING
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

The form has two submit buttons, and I need to detect which of them was clicked and pass this information to the ajax request. However I am having a hard time knowing which of the submit inputs in the form was clicked, as they have also been dynamically generated. Ideas?

Comment: I believe if you assign a submit button (of the `input` and not `button` variety, at least) a value, this value should be passed along with the rest of the form's data. I'm not certain how helpful this might be if you can't adjust the form buttons you're working with, however.

Comment: nope, they are both "input" with types submit and different values, but only the input field of the form is passed as form data - if the value WAS passed along with the rest of the forms data then this would also solve my problem.

Comment: Apologies, I must have been mistaken. In that case, I might suggest binding click event handlers to the buttons instead of a submit event handler to the form, if that's possible. If not, perhaps binding a click event to the entire form, accessing the clicked element though [jQuery's `event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/), and submitting based upon what was clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting a jQuery ajax form with two submit buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365059/submitting-a-jquery-ajax-form-with-two-submit-buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following Connors suggestion of using the click event instead of submit, i have managed to get the the submit button like so:

```
 $("#friendRequestsList").on("click", "[id^=submit1], [id^=submit2]", function(e) {
    var input = this;
    var form = $(input).parent();

    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        url:'URL',
        type:'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            DO SOMETHING
        }

    });
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

of course, this wouldn't work so well if my form had input fields as it wouldn't be triggered on a form submission from a keypress Enter. Also, you still need to append the input identifiying info to the ajax request.

I did this by adding

```
 data: {submit:input.value},
```

to the ajaxSubmit settings

Answer (score 0):

**I hope it will help you :**

```
$("#friendRequestsList").on("submit", "[id^=friendReqResponse-form]", function(){
     var submit1 = $(this).attr('value');

     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('submit1', submit1);

     $.ajax({
        url:'URL',
        type:'post',
        data:formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            DO SOMETHING
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i dont think this will work.
submit1 will be assigned an undefined value which does not indicate the submit button clicked